# Inner product matrix have positive determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, hermitian-matrices

Suppose $|v_1\rangle, |v_2\rangle ,\cdots |v_k\rangle \in S_N$ and suppose a matrix $G$ form by the inner product of these vectors
$$G_{ij}=\langle v_i|v_j\rangle $$
I'm trying to prove that $\text{det} (G)\geq 0$  where equality hold for if vectors are linearly dependent.

---

Since
$$\langle v_i|v_j\rangle =\langle v_j|v_i\rangle ^*\rightarrow G_{ij}=G_{ji}^*\rightarrow G=G^\dagger$$
this means that eigenvalues will be positive. In the diagonal form,
$$G=\text{diag}(g_1,g_2,\cdots ,g_k)$$
The determinant can be written as
$$\text{det}(G)=\prod_ig_i$$
To prove this is positive, We can prove that all the eigenvalues are positive but that is much more restrictive. I'm not sure, How do I proceed? Please help me with this.

Comment: Why does being self-adjoint mean the eigenvalues are positive?  $-I_{n\times n}$ is self-adjoint but has negative determinant if $n$ is odd.  You will need to use properties of the Gram matrix itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matrix is the [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) corresponding to $v_1, \ldots, v_k$. It's clearly Hermitian, and you can show that it is positive-semidefinite by computing $x^\dagger Gx$ and showing it is always non-negative. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
Gx &= \begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1 \mid v_1 \rangle & \langle v_1 \mid v_2\rangle & \cdots & \langle v_1 \mid v_k\rangle \\
\langle v_2 \mid v_1 \rangle & \langle v_2 \mid v_2\rangle & \cdots & \langle v_2 \mid v_k\rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle v_k \mid v_1 \rangle & \langle v_k \mid v_2\rangle & \cdots & \langle v_k \mid v_k\rangle
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_k
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\langle v_1 \mid v_1 \rangle + x_2\langle v_1 \mid v_2\rangle + \cdots + x_k\langle v_1 \mid v_k\rangle \\
x_1\langle v_2 \mid v_1 \rangle + x_2\langle v_2 \mid v_2\rangle + \cdots + x_k\langle v_2 \mid v_k\rangle \\
\vdots \\
x_1\langle v_k \mid v_1 \rangle + x_2\langle v_k \mid v_2\rangle + \cdots + x_k\langle v_k \mid v_k\rangle
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_1 \rangle \\
\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_2 \rangle \\
\vdots \\
\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_k \rangle
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
x^\dagger Gx &= \begin{bmatrix} \overline{x}_1 & \overline{x}_2 & \cdots & \overline{x}_k\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_1 \rangle \\
\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_2 \rangle \\
\vdots \\
\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_k \rangle
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \overline{x}_1\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_1 \rangle +
\overline{x}_2\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_2 \rangle \\
&+ \cdots +
\overline{x}_k\langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid v_k \rangle \\
&= \langle x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \mid x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \rangle \\
&= \|x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \|^2 \ge 0.
\end{align*}
This implies that all the eigenvalues are non-negative. Note also that, if $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are linearly independent, then for non-zero $x$,
$$x^\dagger G x = \|x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + \ldots + x_k v_k \|^2 > 0.$$
This makes $G$ positive-definite, and hence all its eigenvalues are strictly positive.